# SQL database query syntax error: "Encountered YEAR at line 1"

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, syntax-error, derby

Whenever I run this query, I get Syntax error saying "Encountered "YEAR" at line 1. My column name is YEAR and for some reason it won't run, although all the other columns work fine.

```
public void getYears() {

    try {
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pWord);
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT YEAR FROM VEHICLES");
        while(rs.next()) {
            jComboBox1.addItem(rs.getString("YEAR"));
        }
        conn.close();

    } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(VehicleSearch.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

I have the same code for my other columns and they work fine when running, the YEAR column in a VARCHAR(15)

Comment: Reserved word alert!!!!

Comment: Read the docs always....here is the full list: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html

Comment: Thats what I was guessing, when I ran it outside of a string with "" around it worked fine. Is there any way you can do SELECT * FROM VEHICLES "YEAR"; inside the string?

Answer (score 4):

"Year" is a [reserved word in Apache Derby](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.1/ref/rrefkeywords29722.html). In order to use it as a column name, you must escape it by surrounding it with double quotes (`"`):

```
rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT \"YEAR\" FROM VEHICLES");
// Here ---------------------^-----^
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the single quote ( `'` ) for this:

```
rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT 'YEAR' FROM VEHICLES");
```